# How to import android project with native language in eclipse properly

Tags: android, android-ndk

**`It is to be mentioned that I can configure NDK with project containing native code`**

I have downloaded a project from github. But the project is not importing as a project saying "no launcher file found". SO I created a "new project from existing android code". But it has been imported as two projects and showing errors. This is the project hierarchy:
[image]

And this is the project Link.

https://github.com/gnufabio/ics_keyboard_plus

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: I'm not so clear about your question, did you try ADT + "Add native support"? BTW your img is dead.

Comment: Can you please try to import the project of this link https://github.com/gnufabio/ics_keyboard_plus and let me know? :(

Answer (score 0):

**`If you want to "Create project from existing source", you need to create a new directory and then put the project directory tree into that new directory. Then point to the new directory when importing.`**

**For me this worked the best solution !**

- File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace, Next
- Select root directory: /path/to/project
- Projects->Select All
- UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to
  working sets" Finish

[**More info also in this LINK**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8431)

Comment: Can you please try to import the project of this link github.com/gnufabio/ics_keyboard_plus and let me know? :(